# What are the risks of wearing ankle weights during normal activity?

Tags: exercise, exercise-equipment

[In this question, there's some discussion of the effect of wearing ankle weights all day](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/will-wearing-ankle-weights-all-day-long-make-any-difference). Some answers also go into health risks, sadly without citing sources.

What are the risks when wearing ankle weights during 'normal' activities such as walking, taking stairs, walking some more, sitting at a desk?

Answer (score 2):

The advantages and risks have been highlighted in this [article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/218721-pros-cons-of-ankle-weights/). And [this](http://abcnews.go.com/Health/ankle-wrist-weights-pump-pain/story?id=16824588). And countless others. 
 
Yes, you'll burn more calories wearing it. How much you'll burn depends on

- The weight of the ankle weights
- How long it's worn
- The frequency of walking around

However, because you are placing weights on your joints, you might experience joint problems later in life. On the other hand, your body might adjust to accommodate it. 
 
It's not advisable for large weights and for extended periods of times. 
 
But everything depends on the context and you.

Comment: I also strongly advise against it for sports/activities where the limb is used under force away from the axis of the body. For example, in martial arts, no ankle weights for kicking unless you are specifically doing slow, controlled movements for muscle building/patterning. As soon as you even go half speed on a kick, lose the ankle weights. Same for hands, etc.

Comment: @JohnP; I completely agree. One could completely injure one's joints that way.